# Dapper won't read object properties unless explicitly listed as anonymous type

Tags: c#, dapper

Dapper Query isn't populating parameters from typed objects' properties for some reason.

The following code throws an exception saying I must declare @Username, even though credentials contains property `credentials.Username`:

```
const string qryCheckCredentials = "SELECT 1 AS Authenticated FROM dbo.KIUser WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@PasswordMD5";
if (!sqlConn.Query<Boolean>(qryCheckCredentials, param: credentials).FirstOrDefault<Boolean>())
    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException..
```

But if I list out the credential properties explicitly into an anonymous object it works fine:

```
const string qryCheckCredentials = "SELECT 1 AS Authenticated FROM dbo.KIUser WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@PasswordMD5";
if (!sqlConn.Query<Boolean>(qryCheckCredentials, param: new { Username = credentials.Username, PasswordMD5 = credentials.PasswordMD5 } ).FirstOrDefault<Boolean>())
    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException..
```

Any ideas why? I'm getting this issue all over my code and can't see a pattern or figure out what I'm missing.

The Credentials type:

```
[DataContract]
public class Credentials
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Username;
    [DataMember]
    public string PasswordMD5;
}
```

Happens with many types, and listing through them explicitly fixes the issue.

(The DataContract / DataMember attribute decorations are because the object is part of a WDSL interface - probably irrelevant but left here in case they're relevant for some reason beyond my knowledge.)

Comment: Maybe Dapper only works with properties, whereas you have public fields.

Comment: That was exactly the problem thank you @juharr7. Shame on my lazy programming and huge thanks. `public string Username {get; set;}` fixed the issue, removing them brought it back again. Just wasn't seeing it.

Comment: For info, this is already logged, and I plan on fixing it as it is inconsistent that *results* work for both fields and properties, but *parameters* only work with properties. I tried to hack it in a few weeks ago, but it exploded in my face in bad ways - I need to sit down and try again :(

Comment: @Marc this would be a luxury my lazy practices don't really deserve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess is that Dapper only looks at properties, not fields.  Try changing your class to the following and see if it works.

```
[DataContract]
public class Credentials
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Username {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string PasswordMD5 {get; set;}
}
```

It's generally considered better practice to use public properties anyway.